# Access local directory files from a flask api running on docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-volume

My API has to access an image located in a directory on the host server, store it in another directory and access the whole directory multiple times in the host server.

Currently, when I run the API on docker container and it tries to access an image present in a directory on the host, I get the error-

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'W:/datasets/tmp/users/1.jpg'
```

I understand this is because the API is running on an independent server. The directory cannot be mounted to the container as it is large and also will keep increasing in real-time.

How do I access the file system in this situation?
Will SSH using paramiko help in this case or is there another way to do it?

Comment: would attaching an NFS volume to both machines be possible? this would allow to add files from remote machine and access them from docker container with attached NFS volume

Comment: I don't think so. Could you suggest another way?

Comment: how are you connecting to access the image from the remote server? do you have the proper credentials configured foe the connection method?

Comment: Volume mounting doesn't care about sizes. Nothing is actually copied

Comment: @NoamYizraeli that is my question actually. Suppose I am on my windows machine and i started running the docker container with the api. The files are on this windows machine only. How do I get the api to connect and access these files from the container?

Comment: you can create a bind mount which is like linking a host directory and a directory in the container

Comment: Thank you @NoamYizraeli I will try this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will SSH using paramiko help in this case

No, you want a file server, not a shell. If you had an SSH server on the host, then you could use SFTP, but you could also use NFS, as commented

Ultimately, if you're trying to access directories on the same machine as the container, you should be using volume mounts into the container

> cannot be mounted to the container as it is large and also will keep increasing in real time.

So? Have you tried using the mount? What specific issues were you having with it "being large" and mounted?

Comment: The problem with mounting is that the directory that i need access to will keep on updating in real time by another api and stored on the machine locally.  My constantly running api would be called when there is another addition to the directory. If I mount the directory when first running the container, I won't get the updated files that will be added in the future. By 'large' I mean that the directory will keep on updating and increasing the number of files.

Comment: So? Like I said, nothing is copied. The files are always in sync, so "first run" doesn't matter and future updates from the container are seen in the host, and updates from the host are seen by the container

Comment: I understand now. I will just try mounting the directories then. Thank you!

Comment: Suppose the files are present on server 1 and the docker container is running on server 2. How, then would I mount the files that are present on another machine?

Comment: If it's an external host, then you'd use a file server, as answered. Docker provides a NFS solution for mounts, but (S)FTP or an S3-compatible external API call would also work